# The entity type IdentityRole was not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using AspNet Identity 3.0.0.beta3 with and existing database. The configuration I have is very straight forward.

When I try to login, I keep getting this error

ModelItemNotFoundException: The entity type 'IdentityRole' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Here is the code I have:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryAccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IdentityRole { }

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole { }

public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim { }

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim { }

public class UserLoginsExternal : IdentityUserLogin<string> { }


public class HOPContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{

    private string connectionString;

    public HOPContext(string connString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(u => u.Id);
            b.ForRelational().Table("User");
            b.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).ConcurrencyToken();
        });

        builder.Entity<Role>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(r => r.Id);
            b.ForRelational().Table("Role");
            b.Property(r => r.ConcurrencyStamp).ConcurrencyToken();
        });

        builder.Entity<UserClaim>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(uc => uc.Id);
            b.HasOne<User>().WithMany().ForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
            b.ForRelational().Table("UserClaim");
        });

        builder.Entity<RoleClaim>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(rc => rc.Id);
            b.HasOne<Role>().WithMany().ForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId);
            b.ForRelational().Table("RoleClaim");
        });

        builder.Entity<UserRole>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });
            b.ForRelational().Table("UserRole");
        });

        builder.Entity<UserLoginsExternal>(b =>
        {
            b.Key(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey });
            b.HasOne<User>().WithMany().ForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
            b.ForRelational().Table("UserLoginsExternal");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you have the db built perfectly?

Comment: Yes. I have. I just double checked. The table name and foreign keys are defined correctly.

Comment: I feel like your application might be missing a package

Comment: This is what I have in my project.json file

 "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security": "1.0.0-beta3"
 },

Comment: Do you have this very early in OnModelCreating method: base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

Comment: Actually, I have commented that. If I understand correctly I don't think we need to call that. Anyway, even if I call that function, still same error.

Comment: can you also just try : `IdentityDbContext` instead of  `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>`  when inheriting ?

Comment: With just IdentityDbContext, getting this error.

SqlException: Invalid object name 'IdentityUserRole`1'.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration in `Startup.cs, see below :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
...

 services.AddIdentity<User , Role >() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
...
}
```

Make sure to pass your `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` inherited class  to  `services.AddIdentity<TUser,TRole>()`